# Toast.makeText just appear only one time on Andriod Studio

Tags: java, android

I use Toast.makeText to print the Number of an array. However, when I use it in a for- loop. It only printed the first number and did not do anything else.

Comment: You should use Log instead of Toast in a loop.

Comment: post part of your code too

Answer (score 1):

> **Important:** Toasts in android have two kinds of duration: `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`, `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` however they're both slower than a duration of one loop execution or even a whole loop. So, in this case the system might print the first number and waits till the Toast disappears or overwrite all existing Toasts and print the last number or a random one.

There are several ways to handle this:

- If you need to see the numbers your self, you can use :

  ```
  Log.i("My Array Loop", "position: " + position + " value: " + array.get(position));

  //check your Logcat for values
  ```
- If you want to display them to the user using as a Toast, you can achieve this using a `Handler` or a `Timer`, but I prefer using `Handler` since it's more efficiante  :

  1. create a helper class for more flexibility :

     ```
     public class ToastPrintHelper {

     private Context context;
     private ArrayList<Integer> list;
     private int currentPosition = 0;

     public ToastPrintHelper(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
         this.context = context;
         this.list = list;
     }

     public void printValuesEvery(final long periodInMillis) {
         final Handler printHandler = new Handler();

         //initialize your print runnable 
         Runnable printRunnable = new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

                     //print your toast
                     Toast.makeText(
                         context,
                        "position :" + currentPosition + " value: " + list.get(currentPosition),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     //repeat if there are still items to show
                     if (currentPosition < list.size() -1) {
                         currentPosition++;

                         //execute your runnable again but for a delay  
                         printHandler.postDelayed(this, periodInMillis);
                     }
             }
         };

         //execute your runnable without delay for the first time
         printHandler.post(printRunnable);
     }

     }
     ```
  2. Initialize your class this way :

     `ToastPrintHelper printHelper = new ToastPrintHelper(context, list);`
  3. Print values every one second (1000 millis)

     `printHelper.printValuesEvery(1000);`
- In such cases, I'd prefer using an `AlertDialog` with a `ProgressBar` and a `TextView` to make it more visible to the user and increase the UX/UI quality.

> **Note:** The code was not tested, but I believe it has no errors. It can also be better simplified.

**Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 0):

A loop that's running continuously can't execute this sort of actions on view if there's no delay. Either debug the code and see if the code is reaching every iteration number or `Log` the iteration numbers. Also, showing toast on every iteration is blocking your UI thread. You can use a `Handler` to put a delay to see the `Toast` and the iteration number like this:

```java
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Show toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Iteration Number:" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Show toast in about 5 seconds
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
}, 5000);
```